# vi vim delete a word in a special block

Tags: regex, vim, vi

I want to delete "go"s in the comment only, in vi or vim. Would you please let me know how?

```
/*
the following gos should be deleted: in the comment
go
*/

the following go should not be deleted
go


/*
the following go should be deleted: in the comment
go

and some more words
go
*/

the following go should not be deleted
go
```

As a result of delete should be as follows:

```
/*
the following gos should be deleted: in the comment
*/

the following go should not be deleted
go


/*
the following go should be deleted: in the comment

and some more words
*/

the following go should not be deleted
go
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to remove all "go"s in comment block? or just  those "go"s when they sit in whole line alone? please explain why there are still "go"s in your comment block in the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
g/\/\*/.,/\*\//s/\<go\>//g
```

- `g/<pattern>/` - matches lines containing a given pattern, in this case a start of comment
- `.,/<patter>/` - execute the following ex command from the current line to the next line that matches a pattern, which in this example is the end of comment
- `s/<pattern>//g` - replaces all the occurrences of the pattern on each line with an empty string

Answer (score 3):

this line works for your example:

```
%s#/\*\zs\_.\{-}\ze\*/#\=substitute(submatch(0),'go','','g')#
```

some items you may want to take a look in vim's great help doc:

```
:h \zs
:h \ze
:h \_.
:h /star
:h :s\=
:h substitute(
```

Comment: It also deletes the "go" in the sentences itself. I don't think that's OP's intention. Following, I believe, would be closer to what OP wants `g/\v\/\*\_.{-}\*\//,/\v\*\//s/^go$\n`.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I see, in his output, not all "go"s in comment were removed....

Comment: Thanks so much, esp. for the help topics.